# Array of tuples to Map while retaining insertion order

Tags: scala

```
def arrayToMap(fields: Array[CustomClass]): Map[String, CustomClass] = {
  val fieldData = fields.map(f => f.name -> CustomClass(f.name)) // This is Array[(String, CustomClass)], and order is fine at this point
  fieldData.toMap // order gets jumbled up
  /*
  What I've also tried
  
  Map(fieldData : _*)
  */
}
```

why is converting `Array` to `Map` messing up the order? Is there a way to retain the order of the Array of tuples when converting to a `Map`?

Comment: `Maps` don't have an order so saying the order is wrong is plain wrong; when a `Map` is printed or iterated the underlying implementation may traverse the elements in any arbitrary order. Why do you care about the _"order"_?

Comment: The memory structure of maps don't provide an ordering, unless backed by another ordered data structure (`ListMap`, `TreeMap`, `VectorMap` etc). 
The recommended choice of the the structure would depend on what you're trying to achieve (faster lookups, traversals etc).

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use `ListMap` rather than `Map`, but the question remains why the order matters. Also, `Array` is a Java type rather than a pure Scala type, so use `Seq` to allow Scala types to be used as well.

```
import scala.collection.immutable.ListMap

def arrayToMap(fields: Seq[CustomClass]): ListMap[String, CustomClass] =
  ListMap(fields.map(f => f.name -> CustomClass(f.name)):_*)
```